# make a gameObject invisibe without making it inactive

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Willing to make an image invisible to show other gameobjects behind it, but it has co-routine on script which wont run if it's inactive. Now I am making it inactive (with methode `setActive(false)`) to make it invisible based on events. So I want to run the coroutine and also make it invisible.

Is setting order in hierarchy a solution for this?

How to make it invisible without making it inactive/How can I achieve this and make coroutine running?

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/changing-an-objects-transparency-during-runtime.46134/

Comment: How the heck this is duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by turning off the Renderer of the GameObject.

To disable:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
```

**Ref**: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-enabled.html

Comment: What if no renderer is attached like with a panel?

Comment: UI component use Canvas Renderer so you can use `gameObject.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer>().cull = false;`